# Как к существующему объекту добавить возможность быть функцией?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Есть объект

```
let a={b:1}
```

Как к нему добавить возможность чтобы он вызывался с аргументами и чтобы была моя функция?

```
let fn=_=>this.b;
//что тут сделать чтобы
a()+1 //вернуло 2
```

Comment: Превратить объект в функцию? Слава богу, до такого в js еще не додумались))

Comment: В точности такой вызов боюсь не получится. Но можно объявить именованный геттер который возвращает b.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то это должно подойти:

```js
let a={b:1}
a.c=function(){
  return this.b+1;
}
console.log(a.c());
```

Comment: Я бы еще переменную `c` объявил как `_c` чтобы не затереть данные. Да и еще внутрь функции луче передать число которое нужно прибавить.

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто перезаписать переменную `a` нужной функцией:

```js
let a = {
  b: 1
}
console.log(a);

// переписываем переменную
a = function() {
  return this.b;
}.bind(a);
console.log(a() + 1) //вернуло 2
```